OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C
I've been trying to create a custom policy in Azure B2C that is capable of capturing a parameter sent by my Blazor application at the time of /authorize.
I'll explain better:
I created a Blazor Web Assembly .net 8 application and also created my tenant in Azure B2C, everything is working fine, I can open the login page from my application, I can log in and return to my application authenticated with all the due claims.
My idea is to pass a value per parameter to the login page and manipulate it in a custom policy so that it is sent to an Azure Functions API.
My Azure Functions works as an API CONNECTOR, it's not the destination, it's just the claims enricher.
This policy is already working very well for client_credentials type credentials for my daemon applications:
If I run this route, my AZURE FUNCTIONS application is triggered with the correct parameter, executes its routine and enriches the claim according to the business rule
curl --location 'https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxx'
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'AccountId=TESTE123'

Note that I'm using a parameter called AccountId, my Azure function receives this parameter because the custom policy sends it.
But when using the code flow it simply does not work.
Here is what I tried:
https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxx&scope=openid%20offline_access%20profile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7145%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&client-request-id=xxx&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-clie nt-VER=2.33.0&client_info=1&code_challenge=xxx&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=login&nonce=496af997-59c0-436e-ac24-b28246c67f35&state=eyJpZCI6ImQ5ZGNjOD ViLWI3NjUtNGQ0NS1hZjJiLTI4ZTFjMzhhZjdmOSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjo icmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3D%7Cda70e7c3-5122-45f4-896f-527106151c5b&AccountId=TESTE123

AND implicit:
https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=xxx&client_id=xxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&AccountId=123456

Also send AccountId as a parameter
I understand that they are different endpoints /token and /authorize, but in Blazor wasm I do not manipulate /token, I understand that it is something internal to the msal library
These /authorize flows also return to the application Blazor correctly, but do not trigger my azure functions in custom policy
My policy:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="xxx.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="xxx" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxx">

    <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>xxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
    </BasePolicy>

    <BuildingBlocks>

        <ClaimsSchema>
            <ClaimType Id="extension_AccountId">
                <DisplayName>AccounId</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
            </ClaimType>
            <ClaimType Id="extension_SubAccountId">
                <DisplayName>SubAccounId</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
            </ClaimType>
        </ClaimsSchema>

    </BuildingBlocks>

    <ClaimsProviders>
        <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>GetClaim</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-UserMembershipValidator">
                    <DisplayName>TrustfrGetClaim Name</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeamonCustomClaims</Item>
                        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
                        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:AccountId}"/>
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountId" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_SubAccountId" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

        <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
                <DisplayName>Token Issuer Name</DisplayName>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ClientCredentialsUserJourneyId">ClientCredentialsJourney</Item>
                </Metadata>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

    </ClaimsProviders>
    
    <UserJourneys>
        <UserJourney Id="ClientCredentialsJourney">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="REST-UserMembershipValidator" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-UserMembershipValidator" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
        </UserJourney>
    </UserJourneys>
    <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
            <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountId" DefaultValue="No Value" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_SubAccountId" DefaultValue="No Value" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

I don't know if it helps, but this is my code in Blazor that configures the route
InteractiveRequestOptions requestOptions = new()
    {
        Interaction = InteractionType.SignIn,
        ReturnUrl = Navigation.Uri
    };

requestOptions.TryAddAdditionalParameter("prompt", "login");
var extraQueryParametersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["AccountId"] = "TESTE123"
    };
requestOptions.TryAddAdditionalParameter("extraQueryParameters", JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(extraQueryParametersDictionary)));


Navigation.NavigateToLogin("authentication/login", requestOptions);

I believe this should work, as I am basing this documentation on it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow
But I could be wrong.
I haven't applied all the best practices yet, I'm just trying to make it work and then correct and improve everything.
Edit

This is the login, but this parameter is not read in my custom policy
Update
I changed my custom policy and finally managed to capture the sent parameter, but my technical profile responsible for sending to my Azure functions still doesn't work (Only in Code Flow)
So in summary:
If I request a token through client_credential everything works perfectly, but if I use the Flow Code (Human login) the api is not requested.
Policy change:

With this change I get the claim value of AccountId, which is not necessary, but means that it works,
But the API still doesn't get called.

Remembering that this works for the client_Credential is the same policy.

What is the scope you are passing in the client_credentials request

I pass the scope of an app registration looks like 'https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxx/.default'

Then try to pass the same scope in the authorize request too

My API does not have authentication it is public, this API is just an API connector, but created in the custom policy, I need to get the AccountId parameter inside my custom policy, I can do this when I activate /Token, but I need it to work in /Authorize

To call or trigger Azure Function API using Azure AD B2C, check the below:
Create an Azure AD B2C application and expose an API add scope:

Grant API permissions:

Add Identity provider as Microsoft and pass the values of Azure AD B2C application:

The issuer must be in the format https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=xxx
For sample, I generated access token using Implicit flow:
https://rukk33.b2clogin.com/rukk33.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_testruk&client_id=ClientID&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=https://rukk33.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/api.call&response_type=token&prompt=login

Access token generated successfully:

Using the above access token, I am able to call Azure function API successfully:
https://rukfa3394.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=xxx


The issue you are facing is because you are passing invalid scope, you need to pass the API scope and generate the access token and then use the token to call the Azure Function API.

My API is like a Connector API, it does not have authentication and is defined in the custom policy, we are talking about different things

Oh Okay got it. Are you passing the correct scope?

I don't need scope, I'm just trying to do a human login, I don't need access to any API (at this point) just access to my blazor, in this case I'm passing the openid scope and offline_access, just pointing out that I can log in correctly, the problem is that my custom policy is not receiving the accountId parameter

Okay will check and update

I also edited my question to improve understanding, thank you very much for the help
